# Howto set TIMESTAMP type of a column using JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-boot

Hace a entity table with value of created time of a single post of a blog. My code is:

```
@Column(nullable = false, name="created_at", updatable = false, columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
private Timestamp createdAt;
```

But when Spring create the database show an sintaxis error of sql query:

```
create table `posts`
(
    `id` bigint not null auto_increment, 
    `created_at` `TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` not null, 
    `full_content` longtext not null, 
    `full_title` varchar(1024) not null, 
    `permalink` varchar(512) not null, 
    `preview_content` varchar(2048) not null, 
    `preview_title` varchar(30) not null, 
    `show_in_main_page` bit not null, primary key (`id`)
)
```

See the error:

```
`created_at` `TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` not null,
```

Timestamp type and default value is enclosed in quotes and show the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '`TIMESTAMP` not null, `full_content` longtext not null,
>   `full_title` varchar(102' at line 1

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Try removing `columnDefinition`.

Comment: But need the column type is `TIMESTAMP` and the default value `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Other apps connect to same db, need keep the integrity of the database.

Comment: "Spring" does NOT create the database, a JPA provider does. Wonder which one you are using ...

Comment: at line 'created_at' TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,try this one